# Xcode unittest build failed with error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: ios, xcode

My unittest target build failed with below error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MCStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MCStoreTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Basic information:

- Xcode6.2
- iOS8.2 SDK

What I have checked:

- `Symbols Hidden by Default` is No
- `Other Linker Flags` is -framework XCTest
- `Framework Search Paths` is $(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks $(inherited)

Comment: Where is the `MCStore` class implemented?

Comment: it's implemented in my application target.

Comment: And the test target includes that implementation file?

Comment: No, I have added my application target to the unittest target dependencies

Answer (score 152, accepted):

According to this [link](http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/), I need to set `Bundle Loader` with below content in unittest target `Build Settings`

`$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyExistingApp.app/MyExistingApp`

Comment: This answer is a life-saver dude!!! I am so happy I have stumbled upon it!!! So many thanks!!!

Comment: Yep, that was the case.
Be careful, when you have multiple targets in your project!

Comment: Why does this work? And why does this not work out of the box in XCode?

Comment: These line are worth gold!!! Thanks very much. Helped me solving endless Mach-O linker errors in a project with unit-test, ui-test and different deployment targets.

Comment: I had to do this with a brand new project created with XCode 8.2.

Comment: I have too add in Bundle Loader - $(TEST_HOST). Using xcode 9.2 with objective C and Swift

Comment: ADDITIONALLY NOTE - 
Step > Go back to your app target (not the test target), set the Symbols Hidden by Default build setting to
NO 
This option will be visible only when you select "All" under BUILD SETTINGS

Comment: Thank you. Spent hours on this

Comment: Wow! wasted almost 4 hrs fighting with such error in my UITest target. Only your solution worked!

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issue `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64  _OBJC_CLASS_` in my UITest target. I've also spent a lot of time on this issue.

Comment: Many Thanks to you dude. Wasted hours banging my head on wall for this. Tried Cleaning Derived Data, Restarting Xcode, Restarting Mac and only this solution worked.

Comment: Thank you for this GOLD my friend, while I still think Apple must do these tricks out of the box. I've created project with xCode 12 and tests embedded - and still needed those hacks

Comment: Burned through many, many hours trying to solve this one. Thankyou. Apple, I just have a few questions: Why?! Why?! Why?! Why?! Why?! Why?! Why?! Why?! Why?! Why?! Why?! Why?!  Why?!  Why?!

Answer (score 22):

At least as of Xcode 7.3 test targets let you select a "Host Application". In the Test target (but not presently the UI Test target) this automatically populates the "Test Host" build setting, but not the "Bundle Loader", which can lead to classes not being found.

Considering this, if you set your test targets' "Bundle Loader" Build Setting to `$(TEST_HOST)`, it will always contain the right value even if you change the Host Application.

This is effectively *the opposite* of the advice given in the link @yuwen-yan posted, and should amount to less work.

Comment: I found `$(TEST_HOST)` to be the default configuration, however still one of my pods isn't found.

Comment: In Xcode9.2, its now under Test target > Build settings > Testing > Test host. Adding $(TEST_HOST) still works. However, I also did update my cocoapods.

Answer (score 11):

This error may be the result of having wrong test target type, namely *ui test target*.

**UI test targets can't use the internals of the main target**, not even with `@testable` imports. Unit test targets OTOH can use the internals.

[See more details in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42210759/1148030)

(I believe this has changed in some XCode version which causes confusion. Typical way is just to include a huge bunch of files from the original target in the ui test target. A proper way is to design UI tests in such a way that they don't need or use much code from the main target.)

Answer (score 7):

In my case,I got this error when I need to test class that exist in **framework** that was part of my app :

testing framework class.
1. Add testing target to macOS .
2. Select project/targets window. Select the test target.
3. Go to “build phases”, “link binary with libraries”, **add the framework** you want to test .
4. In the test class (setup/teardown), add “import” to the class you want to test from that framework

Answer (score 5):

Experienced the same issue. 
What fixed it for me was setting `enable modules (c and objective-c)` to **YES** in the Testing target `Build Settings`.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was just using the test target on the podfile.

```
target 'MyAppName' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'SwiftLint'
  pod 'RxSwift'
  pod 'RxCocoa'
  pod 'RxDataSources'
  pod 'RxGRDB'

  target 'UnitTestTarget' do
    inherit! :search_paths  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In my particular case I was trying to test `release` configuration and was getting this particular error. After experimenting with different compilation flags I found out that setting `Enable Testability` for release configuration on my projects (not particular targets but might work too) did the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 12.3 (12C33) – I just removed the testing targets and all references. Then created fresh new test targets, and, added back all my test files ✓ *just works*

Comment: I've noticed that test targets somehow break between Xcode releases. So this kind of gets that fresh new start.

Answer (score 3):

I had a unit test target which would not run because of missing symbols.

What fixed it for me was going to

`Project -> Targets -> myTestTarget -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`

and adding the missing library there. I'm using SPM to manage this dependency, probably it was not added properly.

Answer (score 2):

Experienced the same linker error after adding test target to old project which was created 2 or 3 Xcode versions ago. Furthermore, project has various xcodeproject/target/bundle names. All possible *renames*, *cleanings*, `Build settings`, `Build phases`, `Scheme` manipulations did not worked for me.

What did actually worked after a long struggle is **recreating the project along with all targets from scratch in latest Xcode version**. It finally links! And in this case you don't even need to manually modify `Search paths`, `Bundle loader`, Xcode will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents for people like me getting this error using new(2019..) SPM.
I got the same error importing a package in an (old) app.

As importing packages force You to choose target:

[image]

Doing so, you don't have it in Tests, unless You:

a) add Host application too test targrt
b) flag "Allow testing Host Application APIs"

as here:

[image]

now remains the question how to test an app ***without*** running App too during testing....

Answer (score 0):

For me I got a similar error message when I tried writing and running unit tests in a project that previously only had UI tests. After many hours of troubleshooting, I realized the problem was that my current testing target was *only* for UI tests, *not* unit tests.

To fix, I just needed to add a new **Unit Testing Bundle** target, and then make sure that each unit test file I was trying to run had its **Target Membership** set to the new target I just created.

Answer (score -2):

So here is what worked for me...

```
override func setUp() {

    super.setUp()

    let promise = expectation(description: "App has finished running")

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async{
        // Wait on the background thread
        sleep(4)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // Fullfill the promise in the main thread
            promise.fulfill()
        }
    }

    // Initialize the storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // Get the view controller
    sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: ViewController.self)) as? ViewController
    _ = sut.view

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { (_) in
        // Finish set up after the app is done running its code
    }

}// End setUp() Method
```

Answer (score -3):

Below are the steps that I performed to fix the issue while trying to add unit test target in Xcode 9:

1. Go to 'Manage Schemes'.
2. Click on '+' button at the bottom.
3. Select the newly added Target and select 'OK'.
4. Make sure 'Shared' option is selected for the newly added target.