# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRMessaging"

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

Hello I am trying to build a firebase unity project in Xcode, after running pod install
and start building the project I get this error :

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRMessaging", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in libFirebaseCppMessaging.a(messaging_231c52c311096cfce13e67fa91eb9ac5.o)
> "firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteHandle(unsigned long)", referenced from:
> void firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteInternal<void, void firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteInternal(unsigned long, int, char const*)::'lambda'(void*)>(unsigned long, int, char const*, void firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteInternal(unsigned long, int, char const*)::'lambda'(void*) const&) in libFirebaseCppMessaging.a(messaging_231c52c311096cfce13e67fa91eb9ac5.o)
> "firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::ReleaseMutexAndRunCallback(unsigned long)", referenced from:
> void firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteInternal<void, void firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteInternal(unsigned long, int, char const*)::'lambda'(void*)>(unsigned long, int, char const*, void firebase::ReferenceCountedFutureImpl::CompleteInternal(unsigned long, int, char const*)::'lambda'(void*) const&) in libFirebaseCppMessaging.a(messaging_231c52c311096cfce13e67fa91eb9ac5.o)
> "firebase::util::ClassMethodImplementationCache::ReplaceOrAddMethod(objc_class*, objc_selector*, objc_object* (*)(objc_object*, objc_selector*, ...), objc_class*, bool)", referenced from:
> _FirebaseMessagingHookAppDelegate in libFirebaseCppMessaging.a(messaging_231c52c311096cfce13e67fa91eb9ac5.o)
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

any help?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do is make sure you've added your pod file correctly. Check the syntax is correct and if it's not working at all do a pod deinit, clean your build folder, then reinstall the pod again and run your project.

Making sure there is a link between your target and the file also could be worth looking at. Go to your project manager, select your target, and the link binary with libraries and add your pod file that way.

[Xcode unittest build failed with error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935640/xcode-unittest-build-failed-with-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-6)
this helped also when looking around how to solve this. Best of luck.