# Swift test target - "Undefined symbol: protocol witness table"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a problem testing a Swift app that uses a Swift package. When I try to build the test target, the linker complains about an undefined protocol witness table. This is after I already have added the Swift package to the test target under "frameworks and libraries" in its settings. How do you solve this linker error?

Comment: [Does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30935640/5133585) I don't think this is related to Swift packages.

Comment: Also: are you sure you need the package in your test target? If it's package that you need to build the main target, then you don't need to add it to your test target.