# How to detect if iOS app is running in UI Testing mode

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I would like my app to run special code (e.g. resetting its state) when running in UI Testing mode. I looked at environment variables that are set when the app is running from UI Testing and there aren't any obvious parameters to differentiate between the app running normally vs in UI Testing. Is there a way to find out?

Two workarounds that I'm not satisfied with are:

1. Set `XCUIApplication.launchEnvironment` with some variable that I later check in the app. This isn't good because you have to set it in the `setUp` method of each test file. I tried setting the environment variable from the scheme settings but that doesn't propagate to the app itself when running UI Testing tests.
2. Check for the lack of existence of the environment variable `__XPC_DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This seems very hacky and might only be working now because of a coincidence in how we have our target build settings set up.

Answer (score 61):

I've been researching this myself and came across this question. I ended up going with @LironYahdav's first workaround:

In your UI test:

```
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    app.launchEnvironment = @{@"isUITest": @YES};
    [app launch];
}
```

In your app:

```
NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
if (environment[@"isUITest"]) {
    // Running in a UI test
}
```

@JoeMasilotti's solutions are useful for *unit* tests, because they share the same runtime as the app being tested, but are not relevant for UI tests.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me in Xcode 7. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: the launch environment is now NSDictionary<String, String> nemesis. You can't have @YES now. You must instead use a string.

Comment: swift version: 
`let isUITest = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment["isUITest"] != nil`

Comment: My AppDelegate is written in Objective C and my tests are in Swift. 
That's the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 30):

I didn't succeed with setting a launch environment, but got it to work with launch arguments.

In your tests `setUp()` function add:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments = ["testMode"]
app.launch()
```

In your production code add a check like:

```
let testMode =  NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments.contains("testMode")
if testMode {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Verified using Xcode 7.1.1.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. After launching the app from within a UI test, the `NSProcessInfo` arguments don't contain the test string. Xcode 7.3b3.

Comment: Getting the same thing in 7.3. I set the launchArguments in setup, but if I break point on the next line, the launchArguments are empty. It's as if they are not being stored.

Comment: Launch Arguments are different than an environment I believe. 
According to the Apple docs... NSProcessInfo has two process information properties that we want to examine.  

The first is "arguments" : Array of string with the command-line arguments for the process

The second is "environment": The variable names (keys) and their values in the environment from which the process was launched.

You should note the key differences between these and that is "environment from which the process was launched" as opposed to "command line arguments".

Comment: so putting the launchArguments is valid (if launching from the command line) but you must also check for these launchArgs in your code.  You cannot check the processInfo().environment dictionary and expect "arguments" to be inside them.  That would be in the "arguments" property on the NSProcessInfo.  Again see my comment above straight from the Apple Docs.

Comment: It might be a good idea to append the launch arguments instead of assigning to not overwrite other possible arguments: app.launchArguments.append("testMode")

Comment: newer versions of Xcode/swift use `import Foundation` and `ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("testMode")` to check for the flag in the app. This along with the above worked for me.

Comment: Be sure to mark the reading of args with #if DEBUG #endif to avoid leaving open backdoors

Answer (score 7):

You can use **Preprocessor Macros** for this. I found that you have couple of choices:

### New Target

Make a copy of the App's target and use this as the **Target to be Tested**. Any preproocessor macro in this target copy is accessible in code.

One drawback is you will have to add new classes / resources to the copy target as well and sometimes it very easy to forget.

### New Build Configuration

Make a duplicate of the **Debug** build configuration , set any preprocessor macro to this configuration and use it for your test (See screenshots below).

A minor gotcha: whenever you want to *record* a UI Testing session you need to change the *Run* to use the new testing configuration.

Add a duplicate configuration:

[image: Add a duplicate conf]

Use it for your **Test**:

[image: Use it for your *Test*]

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 based on previous answers.

```
class YourApplicationUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

        // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
        continueAfterFailure = false
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launchArguments = ["testMode"]
        app.launch()

        // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        // Use recording to get started writing UI tests.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
    }

}


extension UIApplication {
    public static var isRunningTest: Bool {
        return ProcessInfo().arguments.contains("testMode")
    }
}
```

Then just call UIApplication.isRunningTest in your code.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3 you can check for the `XCInjectBundleInto` key, or something that starts with `XC`.

```
let isInTestMode = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["XCInjectBundleInto"] != nil
```

This works in OS X as well.

Comment: @Phillip Otto - The one thing that Oleander didn't mention is to import Foundation in your class.

Comment: Checking for XCTestConfigurationFilePath seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

I've just added this extension

```
 @available(iOS 9, *)
 extension XCUIApplication {

 func test(){
   launchEnvironment = ["TEST":"true"]
   launch()
  }
 }
```

So I can just use test() instead of launch()

Answer (score 1):

My solution is almost identical to [that of Ciryon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33890800/433373) above, except that for my **macOS Document-based app** I had to prepend **a hyphen** to the argument name:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launchArguments.append("-Testing")
app.launch()
```

...otherwise, "Testing" ends up interpreted as the **name of the document** to open when launching the app, so I was getting an error alert:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to UI tests, but tests in general, create an extension for ProcessInfo

```
public extension ProcessInfo {
    static var isTesting: Bool {
        processInfo.environment["XCTestConfigurationFilePath"] != nil
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if ProcessInfo.isTesting {}
guard !ProcessInfo.isTesting else { return }
```