# Check whether Running the app or Testing UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

I need a set of code to run only when testing the app(UITesting) not when running the app. I have been trying to find whether running the app or it's a UITesting?.

This is new on xcode 8 and above.

Can some help me with this please.

Comment: Make question more clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let the app know if its running Unit tests in a pure Swift project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500940/how-to-let-the-app-know-if-its-running-unit-tests-in-a-pure-swift-project)

Comment: @DanielSumara thats a different question and that doesn't work on xcode anymore for UITesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now we can simply check this with one line of code for "**UITesting**".

> [[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments]
>   containsObject:@"-ui_testing"]

-***ui_testing*** would appear only when testing the app.

Comment: This no longer appears to work in Xcode 14. May have occurred sooner.