# How to boot simulator in headless mode or without window

Tags: ios, xcode, simctl

In android there is a command to boot up a sim without a head or window which takes up significantly less ram e.g.

```
emulator -avd Pixel2Four_API_27 -no-window -no-audio -no-snapshot-load
```

Is there such a mode for iOS sims?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't launch simulator when running unittests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134670/dont-launch-simulator-when-running-unittests)

Answer (score 1):

To launch a simulator in headless mode, for example an iPhone 11 :

```
xcrun simctl boot iPhone\ 11
```

If you want the list of all simulator available, use this command :

```
instruments -s devices
```

At any moment, you can see the UI of your simulator by launching the simulator app :

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/
```