# Keep iOS simulator minimalized/not focused during tests

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to not focus and keep the iOS simulator minimalized at the beginning of tests? I have tried look into Xcode's behaviours menu but without luck.

**Further explenation:**

I still want Xcode to run an app but also preserve its minimalized or out of focus state.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134670/dont-launch-simulator-when-running-unittests etc. ?

Comment: On second thought. I don't think so. I still want simulator to run but in "background".

Comment: Well I think it does lead to the answer, namely if you use `xcodebuild` you run "headless" but otherwise no, I don't think there's a way to keep the Simulator from popping up visibly. You could submit this as an enhancement request to Apple, though frankly I don't see the use for it, because if you really care you'll just say `xcodebuild` at the command line. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/409/?time=145